# Only one parameter being queried in a prepared statement with multiple fields

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am getting values from multiple form fields and using a prepared statement to query the database. While the code below works for criteria entered in a single field, it doesn't return any values if I enter in more than one field. It seems the reason is that page is only processing the last field entered. when I `echo` the value in `$params` before `$results->execute(array($params));` I only get one value...

Here's what I have:

```
<?php


$dbhost     = "ip_address";
$dbname     = "db_name";
$dbuser     = "db_login";
$dbpass     = "db_pass"; 

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE 1=1";

    foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) 
    { 
      if(!empty($v)) {
        $query .= " AND $k LIKE ?";
        $params[] = '%'.$v;     
      }  
    }   

    $results = $conn->prepare($query);
    $results->execute($params);

    $results->bindColumn(1, $no);
    $results->bindColumn(2, $date);
    $results->bindColumn(3, $name);
    $results->bindColumn(4, $id);
    $results->bindColumn(5, $path);

?>
```

### EDIT:

I changed the code above to the working script

Comment: Your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: `$params[] = $v;` and `$results->execute($params);`?

Comment: mkjasinski - Yours and xpy's answer solved this problem. I'd like to give you both credit if possible

Comment: YCS - There is more protection in place than what I have posted but where do you see the problem? I'm new with prepared statements and want to get them right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first define `$params` as an array and then do it like @mkjasinski said. Also the `prepare` is done before the complete query build, thus the query that is sent to the Database is:

`SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE 1=1`

I believe that doing those two right will get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I shuffled the prepare around and forgot to put it back